# xml format getting changed while serializing

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

We are tyring to work on this xml in ie11 browser .

```
<script id="Customer" type="application/xml">
    <form id="customer">
    <firstname></firstname>
    <middlename></middlename>
    <lastname></lastname>
    </form>

</script>
```

we are trying to set atttrbute for the node.

```
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var fieldID = "firstname";
    var formID = "Customer";
    doc = parser.parseFromString(document.getElementById(formID).innerHTML, "application/xml");


    x=doc.getElementsByTagName(fieldID);



    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {


        doc.getElementsByTagName(fieldID)[i].setAttribute(attrName,value);


        document.getElementById(formID).innerHTML  = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc);


    }
```

We are able to set the attribute value ... but when serializing the node and saving it to innerHTML, the xml tags which are empty are getting changed to the following format.

Please help to convert this

```
<firstname />
<middlename attr="value"></middlename>
<lastname />
```

to

```
<firstname></firstname>
<middlename attr="value"></middlename>
<lastname></lastname>
```

Comment: You know that for an XML parser the two XMLs are equal? Short empty tags are only an optimization. Some serializers have options to avoid them (and the use depends on the document type). But the DOM XMLSerializer does not have options.

Comment: yes we do understand but our specific need is to get other format. Is there anyway to set attribute to xml without changing the format. if so please help us.